# Adding data to more than one DE from Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

We have a journey in which we are pushing data from Rest API. It is working absolutely fine but now business wants to push the same data or subset of original data to a different Data Extension. Is it possible to achieve the same without making another rest call? Is there any automation or event which can be triggered as soon data is pushed to first DE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Update Contact" activity with Data Binding to insert the Data pushed from REST API to another Data Extension (DE2). Here is how you will configure the activity.

```
DE2.Field1 = {{Event.Event-Definition-Key.Field1}}
DE2.Field2 = {{Event.Event-Definition-Key.Field2}}
DE2.Field3 = {{Event.Event-Definition-Key.Field3}}
```

Please note that the Update Activity will upsert the data meaning that a record from the same subscriber (ContactKey) will be updated if he is injected twice in the journey.